# Smarty template illegal string at runtime

Tags: php, smarty

In my php file, I query a view and then assign the result to Smarty variables.

```
$sql = "";
$date_range = false;

$conditions = [];
$parameters = [];

if(strlen($_GET['eid'])>0){
    $eid = $_GET['eid'];
    $parameters[] = $eid; 
    $conditions[] = "employee_id = ?";
}
else
{
    $eid = '';
}

if(strlen($_GET['tid'])>0){
    $tid = $_GET['tid'];
    $parameters[] = $tid; 
    $conditions[] = "training_id = ?";
}
else
{
    $tid = '';
}

debug_to_console('starting date value ' .$_GET['sd']);
if(strlen($_GET['sd']) > 0){


        $sd = $_GET['sd'];
        $date_range = 'true';

}
else
{
    $date_range = 'false';
    $sd = '';
}

debug_to_console('ending date value ' .$_GET['ed']);
if(strlen($_GET['ed']) > 0){

        $ed = $_GET['ed'];
        $date_range = 'true';

}
else
{
    $date_range = 'false';
    $ed = '';
}

if ($date_range == 'true')
{
    $conditions[] = "class_date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
    $parameters[] = $sd;
    $parameters[] = $ed;
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from viewSingleTraining";
if($conditions)
{
    $sql .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute($parameters);
$total_pages = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$sql = "SELECT * from viewSingleTraining";
if($conditions)
{
    $sql .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}
$sql .= " LIMIT ?, ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$parameters[] = $offset;
$parameters[] = $records_per_page;
$stmt->execute($parameters);
$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$smarty->assign('rows', $rows);
$smarty->assign('pageno', $pageno);
$smarty->assign('eid', $eid);
$smarty->assign('tid', $tid);
$smarty->assign('sd', $sd);
$smarty->assign('ed', $ed);
$smarty->assign('total_pages', $total_pages);
$smarty->assign('dir', $INC_DIR);
$smarty->display($INC_DIR. '/views/searchresult.tpl');
```

In the .tpl file I loop the $rows array to build a table like this

```
{foreach $rows as $r}
            <tr>
                <td>{$r.fullname}</td>
                <td>{$r.department}</td>
                <td>{$r.class_title}</td>
                <td>{$r.class_date}</td>
                <td>{$r.class_end_date}</td>
                <td>{$r.class_hours}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" style="margin:5px;" class="form-check-input" {if $r.cfs =='1'}checked="checked"{/if}></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" style="margin:5px;" class="form-check-input" {if $r.cea =='1'}checked="checked"{/if}></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" style="margin:5px;" class="form-check-input" {if $r.ceu =='1'}checked="checked"{/if}></td>
            </tr>
        {/foreach}
```

For each column in the table, I get an error like this:
Illegal string offset 'fullname' in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.3.9-0\apache2\htdocs\templates_c\363f8c8c6607635d87e449dc20506adfdfc7d7b0_0.file.searchresult.tpl.php on line 133

***EDIT 10/15/2019 22:11***
This is the vardump of values

```
array(13) 
{ ["fullname"]=> string(11) "Randy" 
["department"]=> string(14) "Administration" 
["id"]=> string(5) "58362" 
["training_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
["employee_id"]=> string(4) "1101" 
["class_title"]=> string(71) "Recipient Rights Training(Classroom/ online) in nonresidentiaal Setting" 
["class_date"]=> string(16) "1/9/2017 0:00:00" 
["class_end_date"]=> NULL 
["class_hours"]=> string(1) "1" 
["cfs"]=> string(1) "0" 
["cae"]=> string(1) "0" 
["ceu"]=> string(1) "0" 
["description"]=> string(836) "This training is intended for case managers, therapists, administrative staff, and support staff. In addition to recipient rights as defined by the Michigan Mental Health Code, it includes information concerning Substance Abuse Recipient Rights, Appeals and Grievance, Advance Directives. This training serves as both the refresher and new hire orientation for non residential staff. This training's objectives are as follows: 1. To highlight the rights of recipients guaranteed by the Michigan Mental Health Code. 2. To ensure that employees understand they must report abuse, neglect and other allegations of rights violations. 3. To ensure employees understand when and how to report abuse, neglect and other alleged recipient rights violations. This class mayb e taken in Classroom style at N180 or via N180 online training system" 
}
```

The data in the view is clean. I don't know why this error happens.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is `$rows` ... an array, or the literal recordset?  What does the output show for `var_dump($rows);`? Please append the details to the question, and not in another comment.

Comment: I added some more info. Thanks Paul

Comment: I am wondering if some of the content in the description is causing problems like the commas or apostrophes etc

Answer (score 2):

i think foreach syntax will be

```
{foreach from=$rows item=r}
   <td>{$r.fullname}</td>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thank you bob_1982, that did not solve the issue, but it is useful. Strangely I had use the other foreach syntax in another project.